# Big Sur zsh Finder issue

Tags: terminal, zsh, macos-big-sur

Can you help me to figure out something?

Each time I launch Terminal app my Finder windows close and relaunch again.

This is very annoying to me and I didn't have this before (when was using **bash**).

Comment: You may have better luck with this question on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), since this seems to be very mac-specific. One thing to check is the various startup files used by `zsh`, and see if there's anything different from the `bash` versions. There's a list of the startup files [here](https://medium.com/@rajsek/zsh-bash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc-e30045652f2e).

Comment: @DenisStesenko: I would first find out, whether the problem is related to Terminal.app, or to zsh. Therefore, once you have a new shell, create a _login subshell_ with `zsh -l`, and see whether the weird behaviour of Finder occurs here too.

Comment: @user1934428 that is good advice, thx!